# An LP problem from David G. Luenberger's Linear and Nonlinear Programming book

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

Could someone help me to solve the following problem?

A class of piecewise linear functions can be represented as $f(x) = Maximum (c_{1}^Tx+ d_{1}, c_{2}^Tx, \cdots, c_{p}^Tx + d_{p})$. For such a function $f$, consider the problem
\begin{equation*}
\text{minimize} \hspace{.8em} f(x)\\
\text{subject to} \hspace{.8em} Ax = b\\
\hspace{2 cm} x \geq 0.
\end{equation*}
Show how to convert this problem to a linear programming problem.

Regards,

R3

Comment: The above is right, but the $y$ is not necessarily larger than $0$. It can be replaced by $u-v$ with $u, v\ge 0$

Answer (score 3):

Introduce a new variable $y$, and rewrite as follows:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & y \\
\text{subject to} & c_i^Tx  + d_i \leq y, ~i=1,2,\dots, p \\
&A x = b \\
&x \geq 0
\end{array}

Comment: Thanks @Michael Grant. In this case this new variable $y$ is defined as $y=f$, right? So to convert in standard form should become something like this?\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize} & y \\
\text{subject to} & c_i^Tx  + d_i + r = y, ~i=1,2,\dots, p \\
&A x = b \\
&x \geq 0, y \geq 0, r \geq 0
\end{array}

Comment: Yes, $y=f(x)$ at the optimal solution.

Comment: Your conversion to equality-constrained standard form is correct. But that is not necessary to simply show that the problem is an LP. A linear program can have any combination of linear equations and inequalities.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Yes I was trying to convert to an equality standard form though that's not the question objective.
Could you suggest me some good references about LPs or Operations Research?

Comment: @MichaelGrant In your solution, $y$ has to be unrestricted right? We cannot assumte that $y \ge 0$ because $d_i$ can be negative as well.